# uploading .csv file into data base in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, opencv

This is my way of reading and saving into table which is working but it's very slow, I had a file consists of 360K records, this way took more than a day to parse them and save into database.
I'm looking for a better way

`    public void parseEntitiesListFile() throws CsvValidationException, IOException {

```
        List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileDirctory));
        csvReader.skip(1);
     
      String[] values = null;
      
      while(true) {
          values = csvReader.readNext();
          FFIList fFIListObject = new FFIList(); 
          fFIListObject.setGIIN(values[0]);
          fFIListObject.setFINm(values[1]);
          fFIListObject.setCountryNm(values[2]);
          fFIListService.saveFFIListEntity(fFIListObject);            
      }
      
      
}
```

`

Comment: FYI, some of the more powerful databases have a feature to directly load files into a table. For example, [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) in Postgres.

Comment: @Ali Ouda You can make use of liquibase to load that CSV data into data base tables: Please refer to this document: https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of spring batch to store the .csv data into the database, which has a job Launcher, job, and step(it consist of ItemReader, ItemProcessor, Itemwritter).
for reference visit this link
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/